# What's the best way to call an application helper from a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

I'd like to format values of a JSON response, to appear the same as how they would in a view.

Consider the object, `user = { id: 323 }`; a helper method (`format_name`) has been created to make the value more presentable in the view:

```
<div>
  <%= format_name(user[:id]) %> 
  <% # appears as: <span class="user" data-user-id="323">John Doe</span> %>
</div>
```

For known reasons, this isn't available in the controller.  The following fails:

```
class ApplicationHelper

  def format_name
    # ...
  end
end


class UserController < ApplicationController

  def view

    # ...<setup user info>...

    user_formatted = {
      id: user[:id], 
      formatted: format_name(user[:id]) # helper method
    }

    respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: user_formatted.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

I'm curious how one might use the helper method in the controller.

I've tried:

- `view_context.format_name`
- creating a partial (e.g., `_view.json.erb`) to call the helper and render json
- setting `helper_method :format_name` in the ApplicationController

Comment: I'll be the one to day it :). For the use case you describe, you should be using a serialization library such as [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). Formatting JSON in a control is generally bad practice. You can use view helpers in serializers (which you can think of as a 'view' for JSON). And it keeps that formatting code out of your controller.

Comment: @chrismanderson it's been a lonnnnng time since I've done extensive Rails development; I welcome any sage advice.

Comment: Definitely check out AMS then. It's now the default serializer for Rails APIs and is part of the rails-api setup.

Comment: Excuse me, but what are known reasons that `format_name` isn't available in the controller.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla If I understand your question correctly, as far as I can remember, helpers are primarily for views, unless explicitly stated in some way, which I'm trying to figure out through my question.

Comment: The @7ukm3n 's anwers explain who to use a helper method inside a controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by either including your helper module in the controller, or you can use `module_function` to declare your helper method as callable directly on the module, sort of like a class method.

Say that your helper function is declared in this helper module:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def format_name(user_id)
    # do stuff
  end
  module_function :format_name  # Here's the "magic" line
end
```

By adding that `module_function :format_name` line, you can now call your helper function just like `ApplicationHelper.format_name(user[:id])` in the controller.

Comment: Where does the `MyHelper` come from? is that another module?  I received an error when `ApplicationHelper.format_name`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to update that part of my answer. Edit: it's updated now.

Comment: Ahh I tried that and got an error, but I think that's more related to the helper function... checking on it now, thx

Comment: As you wrote the helper function in your code example above, it is missing a parameter, but you call it with one parameter. If you wrote your example exactly like your code, that might be why. Otherwise, it's probably just some logic error. Oh, and if you use any instance variables (`@something`) in that helper function, you might have to replace them, since the helper function does not have the same scope as the controller.

Comment: I didn't, but I hit a block because I was using `allow?` in the helper, which was an undefined message.  Since that seems to be a separate problem from the one asked, I'm going to guess this is good enough.

Answer (score 5):

(Moving this from a comment to an answer) I would recommend not doing this formatting in your controller but instead using [ActiveModelSerializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to handle it. It's part of the rails-api setup and is now ships by default in Rails 5. For your situation, you would do something like:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include ApplicationHelper

  attributes :id, :formatted

  def formatted
    format_name(object)
  end
end
```

And in your controller, you can just do

```
def show
  render json: User.find(params[:id)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
###helper    
module MyHelper
  def format_name(user_id)
     #code goes here
  end
end

###html
<div>
  <%= format_name(user[:id]) %> 
</div>

###controller
class SampleController < ApplicationController
  include MyHelper

  def view
    puts format_name(user[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: This was helpful, the reason I didn’t select it is because I think it exposes all functions to the controller and the selected answer seems like it does a little better at preventing side effects. Though, I’m sure this method could be adapted to accommodate that concern